# Looking for a 3rd method to achieve results in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a Very Long Equation. (VLE).
If the `VLE` has a certain property `(A1 = 5, for example)`,
I'd like to take the `Absolute value of VLE`, instead of just `VLE`.
Normally, this would look like

```
=if(A1=5, Abs(VLE),VLE)
```

Alternatively, I'd have a helper column,

```
=if(A1=5,ABS(B1),B1)
```

and refer everything there.

I'm wondering if there is a `3rd method`, one that only has `VLE written once`, and that doesn't use a helper column.
Could the sumifs that grabs the VLE's squeeze in an array (while already using an OR?) Is there a way to have an array be self-referencing? Or am I stuck with one of the two previously proposed solutions?

VBA is always a possibility... but at that point I'd rather re-write a number of equations to prevent that.

Comment: if A1=5 are you sure VLE is <0 always?

Comment: If that was the case it would be an easy If(A1=5,-1,1). It could be either direction, which is why I'd like to use ABS. If I could always make sure it was negative, that would also work. Just trying to get the signs always going in the same direction

Comment: This is a great question, and a situation I run into all the time. I dream of a VBA function `Function With(name,NameValueFormula , myFormula)` , that evaluates _NameValueFormula_, then replaces every occurrence of _name_ with  the value of _nameValueFormula_ in _myFormula_  then evaluates& returns _myFormula_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `C4-D4` be a placeholder for the long formula.
Then, if you can change the condition in `A1`
such that `A1` is always either 1 or 2, and 2 means use the absolute value,
the main column formula would be just
`=((C4-D4)^$A$1)^(1/$A$1)`.
If the condition in `A1` can not be changed and you can reserve one extra cell,  say, `A2` as `=1+(A1=5)`, then 
the main column formula would be
`=((C4-D4)^$A$2)^(1/$A$2)`.
Otherwise you always can use a longer version
`=((C4-D4)^(1+(--($A$1=5))))^(1-(--($A$1=5))/2)`.

Just beware that this could result in accuracy loss or overflow.

Comment: This is great! A  modifications:the 2010 version of excel doesn't quite let you use true-false like that (calling it 1 and 0 directly) - so I'm going to replace that section with if statements. Alternatively, someone could put in -- after the statements to convert them to 1/0

Answer (score 1):

A third option is to use a User Defined Function (*UDF*):

```
Public Function ConditionalAbsolute(v As Variant, boo As Boolean) As Variant
    If boo Then
        ConditionalAbsolute = Abs(v)
    Else
        ConditionalAbsolute = v
    End If
End Function
```

For example:

[image]

The first argument is the "long formula"; the second argument is the expression that is either *True* or *False*.

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as **.xlsm** rather than **.xlsx**

To remove the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the UDF from Excel:

```
=CondionalAbsolute(A1+B1,C1=0)
```

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**